# Can I take multiple cars into Mexico from the U.S.?

Tags: borders, customs-and-immigration, mexico, automobiles

I've taken my car into Mexico multiple times from the United States, on a Tourist visa.  Is it possible to take **more than one** car registered to me at the same time (obviously with a second driver)?

Comment: Do they actually check who the car is registered to? Even if they do, I'd assume unless it's reported stolen, it should be ok...

Comment: Yes, they require proof of vehicle ownership when entering the country. And if it's not registered to you, you must have a signed letter from the owner indicating that you are authorized to take the vehicle into Mexico (or so I understand--I've never actually tried doing that). And their rules have become much more strict in the last few months... so I want to be doubly sure before I drive _two_ cars 800 miles just to find out I can only take one into the country. :)

Comment: The only time I've driven to Mexico, we didn't slow below 20mph as we crossed the border, let alone stop and be asked any questions! (This was about 5 years ago though). Coming back was a very different story though, I think we queued for about 2 hours to get back into the states..

Comment: @Gagravarr: I'm guessing you never left the free-trade zone (first ~25km inside the border), then... if you had, you would have been stopped and had your car inspected, and probably been turned back.  Or at least that's how they do it now. I wasn't driving into Mexico 5 years ago, so maybe they were more relaxed then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the US Consulate:

> Tourists to Mexico wishing to travel beyond the border zone with their
>   car must obtain a temporary import permit or risk having their car
>   confiscated by Mexican customs officials.
>
> To acquire a permit, one must submit evidence of citizenship, title
>   for the car, a car registration certificate and a driver's license to
>   a Banjercito branch located at a Mexican Customs office at the port of
>   entry, and pay a processing fee.
>
> Mexican law also requires the posting of a bond at a Banjercito office
>   to guarantee the departure of the car from Mexico within a time period
>   determined at the time of the application. For this purpose, American
>   Express, Visa or MasterCard credit card holders will be asked to
>   provide credit card information; others will need to make a cash
>   deposit of between $200 and $400, depending on the age of the car.
>   Please do not forget to ask for your receipt from Banjército.
>
> In order to recover this bond or avoid credit card charges, travelers
>   must return to any Mexican Customs office immediately prior to
>   departing Mexico. Disregard any advice, official or unofficial, that
>   vehicle permits can be obtained at checkpoints in the interior of
>   Mexico. Avoid individuals outside vehicle permit offices offering to
>   obtain the permits without waiting in line.
>
> If the proper permit cannot be obtained at the Banjercito branch at
>   the port of entry, do not proceed to the interior where travelers may
>   be incarcerated, fined and/or have their vehicle seized at
>   immigration/customs checkpoints.

So it sounds really like as long as you have the ownership papers and registration, it doesn't matter how many cars in your convoy :D

Answer (score 3):

To add to Mark Mayo's Answer.

There is no limit on the number of cars. If you don't own the car you need a letter from who does. IE if the car is leased you need a letter from the leasing company; If the Bank still owns the car, you need a letter from the bank; etc. The letter needs to say you are authorized to take the vehicle into Mexico. Since you, (the owner), would be with them it should be easier, but you may still want to write the letter for them to keep in the car.

I would refer to Mark's quotation for requirements and add, If you don't have a tourist permit you can not pass checkpoints. The tourist permits can not be obtained at checkpoints. You also need to insure vehicles.

This information comes from [Instant Mexico Auto Insurance](http://www.instant-mex-auto-insur.com/), they insure vehicles for groups of people involved in international off road racing, and pit stop crews are often driving cars that all belong to the Motor-sporting company.

Answer (score 0):

You can only enter Mexico with 2 motor vehicles that are in your name.  Additional vehicles must be in another persons name and that person must be present.  This is what we've found when entering last December (2019) with a motorhome pulling a car with a Vespa scooter on a hitch carrier.  I'm online now looking to see if there's a work around as I want to enter this December with the same vehicles but my wife is no longer here to sign for the car as she did before.